# Dedicated C# class to update progressbar

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I would like to make a dedicated class to update the progress bar in my apps (in this case a WPF progressbar). I did something like this :

```
public class ProgressBarUpdate : IDisposable
{
    private readonly double _delta;
    private int _current;
    private int _total;
    private readonly ProgressBar _pb;

    public ProgressBarUpdate(ProgressBar pb, int total)
    {
        _pb = pb;
        _total = total;
        // the pb.Maximum is a double so it doesn`t get truncated
        _delta = _pb.Maximum / total; 
        _current = 0;
        _pb.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _pb.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        _current = 0;
    }
    public void UpdateProgress()
    {
        _pb.Value =(int)_delta * (++_current);
    }
```

That i use like this (in the UI thread) :

```
using (var pu = new ProgressBarUpdate(pb, totalCount)
{
  for (x=0; x<totalCount; x++)
  {
     // operations here 
     pu.UpdateProgress()
  }
}
```

But the UI, probably blocked, is not updating correctly. What is the best way to display all the progress?

Comment: Might it be, that your UI is not only "not updating" but also blocking?

Comment: have you debugged into it to make sure `_pb.Value` is getting changed as you expect inside the `UpdateProgress` call?

Comment: *But this is not updating correctly in my UI.* What does that mean?

Comment: You are probably doing your `using(var pu ... blah` on the UI thread and blocking any drawing from happening until the work is complete

Comment: Yes sorry, it updates and the Value is correct it just don`t updates the UI because is blocked probably.

Comment: Your calculations for the progress bar value are unnecessary, because `ProgressBar` has a [Maximum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.maximum.aspx) property. It is 100 by default, but you can change this to your actual total.

Comment: Stop blocking the UI thread. Put the long running task on another thread.

Comment: I did not wanted to make a new thread for everything i do cause the purpose was to create this class and reuse everywhere. The question is if i can put this new instance in a new thread and force the UI to update everytime this is called

Comment: Consider `_pb.Value = _delta * (++_current);` such that the update occurs after incrementing current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winforms/WPF program is an `Eventing` system. There is a single thread which continuously processes events from an event queue. That is its main job and ideally that is the only thing which it should do. Any sort of UI activity generates events in the event queue - like you move your mouse over the window or click something or some other window overlaps your window and then again when it goes away from the overlapped position. All these events are processed by the UI thread and that keeps the UI *updated* all the time.

Further, Winforms/WPF make it necessary to access and/or update controls and their properties in a thread safe manner by allowing it only on the UI thread.

If you block this UI thread or do some other CPU bound calculation on it, then your UI *responsiveness* and *updated* behavior will suffer. Worst case UI will freeze.

Hence the correct answer for you is to do your calculation loop on another worker thread and only update the progress bar UI by marshaling the call to UI thread using the `Dispatcher`.

However, to answer your question and satisfy your inquisition, here is something that is possible  - but it is **bad practice** and your should **never do the following...**:

To make it simple, when you update the `Value` property of the progress bar, it invalidates the progress bar UI - so, UI must update. Hence lets say an event is generated in the event queue which will cause some code to run which will update the UI. However, you are running in a loop over the UI thread - so, the thread has no chance to process this event unless your loop is over. Hence you don't see any UI update. The trick is to make the UI thread process that event before you make the next update on the `Value` of progress bar. You can do this by forcefully invoking a lower priority item into the event queue - so that normal and higher priority items are processed before going to the next iteration.

```
using (var pu = new ProgressBarUpdate(pb, totalCount))
{
  for (int x = 0; x < totalCount ; x++)
  {
     // operations here 
     pu.UpdateProgress();

     Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(()=>{}));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your complete reply, so if i got it right the code you added is good but in general should be in another thread? Would be possible to move the thread operation in the separate class or it needs to be in the main UI code?

Comment: Btw if I try this i get "An object reference is required for the non-static field"

Comment: Ok I found out : i put this in the UpdateProgress method and it works : `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => { }));`

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing your work, and calling UpdateProgress, on the UI thread then it won't update until you finish the work and the UI thread can do other work (like refresh the UI). So this will never work.

If you're doing your work on a background thread, then you need to use a Dispatcher to marshal the setting the value to the UI thread.

Here's an example from http://tech.pro/tutorial/800/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher

```
if (!myCheckBox.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
  myCheckBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
    new Action(
      delegate()
      {
        myCheckBox.IsChecked = true;
      }
  ));
}
else
{
  myCheckBox.IsChecked = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the work is done in the UI thread. I wanted to make a general purpose class to always update any progressbar used in the main thread. The problem is in fact that this never redraw the UI until the loop is finished.

Comment: Well is not long work, I wanted to have a progress bar indicating is working. It`s just few seconds to reload some file.

Comment: @DomenicoAlessi Your definition of "long work" and a computer's definition of "long work" are different. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public ProgressBarUpdate(ProgressBar pb, int total)
{
    _pb = pb;
    _total = total;
    _delta = _pb.MaxValue/((double)total);  /make sure you do not truncate delta
    _current = 0;
    _pb.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

}
public void Dispose()
{
    _pb.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    _current = 0;
}
public void UpdateProgress()
{
    _pb.Value = (int)( _delta * (++_current)); //update after the increment
}
```

I suggest also using `float` instead of `double`.

Comment: Yes fixed,in the WPF version the MaxValue is called Maximum and is a double so there is no need to recast. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've been saying you want to avoid using threads, I assume because you don't want unnecessary complication, but it's really not a big deal. It's a very simple matter to make an operation multi-threaded. Even for very short and simple tasks, this is the most straightforward way to achieve what you want. Using [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx), it would look something like this:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

...

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    for (...) {
        // operation...
        progressBar.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => progressBar.Value = ...);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am going to try this in my next project. Thank you!